# Async Closure Issue Solve in Swift not working?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

**I Have boiled down the problem to this**

this closure :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let data = homeDataSource()
    getPrivatePosts { (posts) in
        print("postsCOUNT" , posts!.count)
        data.posts = posts!
    }
    self.datasource = data
    collectionView?.reloadData()

}
```

prints out "postCOUNT 1 postCOUNT 3"

then when I print the count of data.posts I get 0... whats going on with that?? here is the full code

this is a custom UICollectionView:

```
import LBTAComponents
import Firebase
class homeView: DatasourceController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let data = homeDataSource()
    getPrivatePosts { (posts) in
        print("postsCOUNT" , posts!.count)
        data.posts = posts!
    }
    self.datasource = data
    collectionView?.reloadData()

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width , height: 150)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 0   )
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
}
// just to test
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNewPost", sender: self)
}


func getPrivatePosts(completion : @escaping (_ privatePosts : [Post]?) ->()){
    // fill posts array with posts from all buddys "privataPosts only"


    var ret = [Post]()
    staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("contacts").observe( .value , with: { (snapshot) in

        let dict = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for d in dict{
            if let contactUid = d.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as? String{


                staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child(contactUid).child("privatePosts").observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let posts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    print("postval" , posts)

                    for post in posts{

                        if let dict = post.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                            let fullname = dict["fullname"] as! String
                            let picUrl = dict["picUrl"] as! String
                            let postContent = dict["postContent"] as! String
                            let time = dict["time"] as! Int
                            let uid = dict["uid"] as! String
                            let username = dict["username"] as! String

                            print("first name of person who did the post" , fullname)

                            let reposts = dict["reposts"] as! [String]

                            let downs = dict["downs"] as! [String]
                            // possible issue
                            var comments = [Comment]()

                            let commentArr = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments").children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]

                            for c in commentArr{
                                if let dict = c.value as? [String : AnyObject]{

                                    let cuid = dict["uid"] as! String
                                    let ccommentText = dict["commentText"] as! String
                                    let cpicUrl = dict["picUrl"] as! String
                                    let cusername = dict["username"] as! String
                                    let ctime = dict["time"] as! Int

                                    let com = Comment(uid: cuid, commentText: ccommentText, time: ctime, picUrl: cpicUrl, username: cusername)

                                    comments.append(com)

                                }

                            }

                            print("HERE : post content\(postContent) username : \(username) commentArr \(comments)")

                            let postToAdd = Post(postContent: postContent, picUrl: picUrl, userName: username, fullName: fullname, postID: uid, postTime: time, downs: downs, reposts: reposts, comments: comments)

                            print("LOOK AT MEE   \(postToAdd.userName) is the username of the post object \(postToAdd.postContent) is the contetn")

                            ret.append(postToAdd)
                            print("RET" , ret)
                        }
                    }
                    completion(ret) // this is where the completion block should be called
                })

            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

This is a datasource object :

```
import LBTAComponents
class homeDataSource: Datasource {

var posts = [Post]()



override func numberOfItems(_ section: Int) -> Int {
    print("COUNT " , posts.count)
    return posts.count

}

override func headerClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type]? {
    return [userHeader.self]
}

override func footerClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type]? {
    return [userFooter.self]
}

override func cellClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type] {
    return [userCell.self]
}

override func item(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any? {
    return posts[indexPath.item]
}
```

}

The frame work can be used here :

pod 'LBTAComponents'

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the data structure from Firebase?

Comment: It's **absolutely impossible** to declare a variable with a default value assigned in a closure containing an asynchronous task. It's impossible anyway to return something from a function containing an asynchronous task. Please learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works.

Comment: @rMickeyD the problem has nothing to do with the data base .. I know I have the right objects inside my "ret" post array the issue lies in why the "posts" array is not being filled , thanks for your help

Comment: can you please explain to me ? @vadian

Comment: You have to call completion inside the async block of code, otherwise it calls the completion line before the async finishes and never updates.

Comment: *Asynchronous* – as the name implies – means that the database request returns its data later in time. You need a pattern with a completion handler.

Answer (score 2):

You have the same basic misunderstanding twice.

In the second code section you create your `ret` variable initially empty and then fire of some async tasks.  However you call the completion(ret) outside of the async task so it will fire immediately before the async tasks have finished and therefore return your initial empty value.

The fist code also will suffer the same problem in that you create your postArray initially empty then call your getPrivatePosts function supplying a completion handler but that completion handler will be called in an async task so there could be a delay but you use the value immediately and therefore will return the empty initial value.

Comment: what can I do to fix this??

Comment: It's going to depend on what you want to use the posts property for.  E.G. is this used to populate a UITableView?

Comment: @zackkkkkkk Look at the answer to the question you linked. Look where they call `completion` and compare it to where you call it.

Comment: It is used to populate a custom UIcollection view @UpholderOfTruth thanks for your help :)

Comment: @rmaddy they call it inside the method itself , I tried doing thank too . they call the completion on the main que which I just tried and it didn't change anything... what could be the issue?

Comment: @zackkkkkkk They call it from inside the completion handler of the asynchronous access. You are not. That's the issue with your code.

Comment: I don't really know Firebase itself but from the looks of that getPrivatePosts function it would look like you are calling a function that performs async and when that returns you are running in a loop to call other functions that also run async.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create your posts array in that way. You should create the a mutable array:

```
var posts = [Post]()
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` of your view controller you should then populate the array from your service (Firebase).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getPrivatePosts() { posts in
        self.posts = posts ?? []
    }
}
```

You posts function also is never going to return the data you want from the service since your calling your completion block outside of the scope of the service request. Move the completion block to the bottom of the for loop in the `staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child` part of the `getPrivatePosts` function like so:

```
class func getPrivatePosts(completion : (_ privatePosts : [Post]?) ->.   ()){
    // fill posts array with posts from all buddys "privataPosts only"


    var ret = [Post]()
    staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("contacts").observe( .value , with: { (snapshot) in

        let dict = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for d in dict{
            if let contactUid = d.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as? String{


                staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child(contactUid).child("privatePosts").observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let posts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    print("postval" , posts)

                    for post in posts{

                        if let dict = post.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                            let fullname = dict["fullname"] as! String
                            let picUrl = dict["picUrl"] as! String
                            let postContent = dict["postContent"] as! String
                            let time = dict["time"] as! Int
                            let uid = dict["uid"] as! String
                            let username = dict["username"] as! String

                            print("first name of person who did the post" , fullname)

                            let reposts = dict["reposts"] as! [String]

                            let downs = dict["downs"] as! [String]
                            // possible issue
                            var comments = [Comment]()

                            let commentArr = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments").children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]

                            for c in commentArr{
                                if let dict = c.value as? [String : AnyObject]{

                                    let cuid = dict["uid"] as! String
                                    let ccommentText = dict["commentText"] as! String
                                    let cpicUrl = dict["picUrl"] as! String
                                    let cusername = dict["username"] as! String
                                    let ctime = dict["time"] as! Int

                                    let com = Comment(uid: cuid, commentText: ccommentText, time: ctime, picUrl: cpicUrl, username: cusername)

                                    comments.append(com)

                                }

                            }

                            print("HERE : post content\(postContent) username : \(username) commentArr \(comments)")

                            let postToAdd = Post(postContent: postContent, picUrl: picUrl, userName: username, fullName: fullname, postID: uid, postTime: time, downs: downs, reposts: reposts, comments: comments)

                            print("LOOK AT MEE   \(postToAdd.userName) is the username of the post object \(postToAdd.postContent) is the contetn")

                            ret.append(postToAdd)
                            print("RET" , ret)
                        }
                    }
                    completion(ret) // this is where the completion block should be called
                })

            }
        }

    })
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: could you elaborate on that last part? Im sorry I dont get what part you are referring too

Comment: @zackkkkkkk I moved the completion block call  in the function you posted in your question, let me know if that helps.

Comment: This answer correctly address the OP issue.  Additionally, since the OP is using observe he should also remove the observer at some point in viewController lifecycle such as viewWillDisappear.  For this reason it is preferable to populate in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad if he were to push another viewController on top of this one.

Comment: thanks really appreciate you working this out with me :( unfortunately this did not work , see my updated source code above maybe its another issue? (the updated source code does not include the move of the completion , but dont worry I moved it )  @naturaln0va

Comment: how do u suggest I do this will it effect refreshing of the posts in any way ?? @rMickeyD

Comment: @zackkkkkkk it looks like you need to reload your view when inside of `getPrivatePosts` after setting the posts on your data model. I'm not sure how to reload the UI lib your using, but call the equivalent of `UITableView`'s `reloadData`.

Comment: that didn't work :( see my update I think ive narrowed it down @naturaln0va

Comment: @zackkkkkkk what isn't working? Are your posts getting populated in the data model?

Comment: the population of data.posts is not happening for some reason :( which is my data model @naturaln0va

Comment: @zackkkkkkk there has to be an issue with the other parts of that async function. Are you sure data is being returned?

Comment: the data is being returned at the println "RET" and the ret array is populated  so idk what it could be :( thank you for helping me along this incredibly frustrating time @naturaln0va The problem is I have three post objects inside ret ik for a fact , I return it to the completion and it doesn't get stored into the data.posts

Comment: @zackkkkkkk `postsCOUNT` inside `getPrivatePosts` returns data? You need to call `collectionView?.reloadData()` right after populating your data inside the closure of `getPrivatePosts`.

Comment: @zackkkkkkk one final thing I'd check is making sure your collection view's delegate and data source are hooked up. Check out this code lab from Google: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0 for a walk though on how to make a firebase powered iOS app!